# Android: startActivity() from AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I am trying to use a Button in an AlertDialog to view a webpage.

The problem is that this AlertDialog is located inside a class that extends ItemizedOverlay and doesn't extend Activity, so Eclipse underlines it and gives the following error:

> The method startActivity() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}

I would like to launch activities from the PositiveButton, NeutralButton and NegativeButton, but I am not able to.

In case you need more context, the main Activity is a MapView with some ItemizedOverlay, and I would like to launch a webpage with directions or another activity that does that.

Comment: Wow, that was fast... Thank you very much, it worked perfectly!!
I actually had a Context in my class, so I just had to use it with the new Intent.

Thank you all, guys!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Construct a constructor in the class which contains your alert with `Context` object as a parameter. Assign it to a Context variable.

Use this context variable for creating the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, "Your next activity to be shown");//mContext is the Context variable over here.
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);    
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the answer is provided by you in your question. i.e startActivity is undefined in ClickListener functions. so in oncreate function, initialize a Global variable like

```
Activity myActivity = this;
```

then in onclicklistener, start another activity from this.

```
myActivity.startActivity(xxxxxxxx);
```

This could be one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297642/how-to-apply-custom-view-to-alerdialog-in-android)

In these you write your desired code inside the Positive Button,You can start an Activity by using Intent..

```
startActivity(new Intent (YouPage.this,NewPage.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the context say `context.startActivity();`

if you dont have context try to get it from `getContext();` or `getApplicationContext();` or `getBaseContext();`

Answer (score 0):

Pass context of the activity in constructor of that class and create a field of type activity 
and store context in that activity and then

say

```
Activity activityClass;
```

and initialize it from your constructor

and start activity from that  activiytClass

activityClass.startActivity();